# Can I use Yes or now Popup box for each use not first use?

Tags: javascript

I am using Popup box from YouTube but this jQuery code only use first array in my code. I have list View for 10 items. This code always selected First array for "Yes" or "No" value. please help me how to use this function to effect to all Array?

```
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                        function Confirm() {

                            var input = $("<input />");

                            input.attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "confirm_value");


                            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to buy it?")) {
                                input.val("Yes");
                            } else {
                                input.val("No");
                            }
                            var i;
                            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                         $("form")[i].appendChild(input[0]); // this code always effect first  
                                                                   array If I use forloop, only 
                                                                  last array is going to out 
                                                                   value
                       }
                            
                            
                           
                        }
                        
                    </script>
                }
```

Comment: Show the loop....

Comment: I put for loop. but last array got effected.